# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'create' - THREE.JS cameras\Camera.js

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, camera, internet-explorer-9, three.js

I get this error:
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'create'

When trying to use `three.js` with IE9. The following line of code is causing the problem:

```
THREE.Camera.prototype = Object.create( THREE.Object3D.prototype );
```

in file `cameras\Camera.js`

The strange thing is that it works fine with some computers with IE9 and with other is does not.

Comment: Suddenly I have the same problem :(. Yesterday my stuff was working and today it's not. Funny thing is, I haven’t touched my 3D code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. IE9 was using quirks mode for my page. I solved it by adding a

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

declaration at the very start of my page.

It's also possible that this could have been caused by IE9 using Compatability View to display your page. That could explain the variation in behaviour between computers.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff925952(v=vs.94).aspx) says about `Object.create`:

```
Supported in the following document modes: Internet Explorer 9 standards, 
Internet Explorer 10 standards, and Internet Explorer 11 standards. Not 
supported in the following document modes: Quirks, Internet 
Explorer 6 standards, Internet Explorer 7 standards, Internet Explorer 8 standards.
```

So as you using `IE9`check the compatibility mode if it is set to `standards` or `Quirks`.

Now if you want to do similar thing when on `Quirks` mode then it should look like :

```
 THREE.Camera.prototype = new THREE.Object3D().prototype
```

or ,

```
THREE.Camera.prototype = new THREE.Object3D
```